# HTML - href redirect dynamically

Tags: html, wordpress, href

I am running a Wordpress theme with the following link hard coded to the template. How do I change it depending on the current domain the browser is at. Please note that I am using sub-domains.

From(https://www.foo.com/):

```
<a class="btn" href="https://armoires.foo.com/_Login/Login.php">
```

to(https://www.foo.ch/):

```
<a class="btn" href="https://ch.foo.com/_Login/Login.php">
```

Comment: Just make the link href="/_Login/Login.php">

Comment: Can you edit the particular page ?

Comment: I do have full access to edit the page. My problem is that I have got only one Wildcard certificate, therefore I have created sub-domains to separate my French and Swiss language sites. I need some sort of PHP code that allows me to change the URL of the HREF accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I did a switch case for this to work:

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
switch ($path)
{
case 'www.foo.com':
  $link = 'https://com.foo.com/Login.php';
  break;
case 'www.foo.ch':
  $link = 'https://ch.foo.com/Login.php';
  break;
default:
  $link = 'https://com.foo.com/Login.php';
}
?>
```

Then

```
<a class="btn" href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the domain:

`<a class="btn" href="/_Login/Login.php">`

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<a class="btn" href="https://armoires.foo.com/_Login/Login.php">
```

To:

```
<a class="btn" href="<?php echo home_url( '/_Login/Login.php' ); ?>">
```

This will only work inside a PHP file. Alternatively you'll need to use a relative link.

```
<a class="btn" href="/_Login/Login.php">
```